# Back button without NavController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I need to create a back button that returns to the previous view controller the user was on before going to the page with the back button. I've read that the Navigation controller and barbuttonitems are the way to do it, but with my app the look will not fit at all. I have read that using a custom UIButton to perform these actions will just keep adding the views to the stack instead of releasing them. Is it possible to just use a UIButton to go back to the previous view controller without causing a pile up on the stack? Thanks.

Comment: I have used custom back buttons with segues to ViewControllers in most of my apps. All of them accepted on the Appstore and no memory problems.

Comment: I have custom classed segues that I use to get around in the app. Do you just remove the current view controller from the stack with your back button? All the examples I've seen haven't worked and those are few as everyone seems to succumb to Apples Navigation Controller which is quite ugly at times.

Comment: In your custom class you can dismiss view controllers after segues. Look at this tutorial [link](http://www.bencz.com/hacks/2014/02/07/custom-ios-segues-in-xcode-5/) Hope it'll help you.

Comment: It's crashing now. I think the issue is that there's a few VCs in front of a container. Then the rest of the VCs come to the container. I'll try connecting the container instead.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the above to work either. However, I did find a way to fix my issue. I simply created a NSMutableArray and had it populated with the segues. If current segue is 0, then back goes to object at index 1 in the array which gives me the previous screen no matter where I was. Another use of the array was to also remove the VCs once I passed a certain amount so I can keep the stack clean. Thanks for all the help everyone.